# Parseval's identity

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How to prove the Parseval's identity , I know the formal way but how to justify the interchange between the integral and the sum in a rigorously way , in addition what extra condition does the function have to satisfy , is the continuity enough in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parseval's formula holds for every $L^2$-function, even if it's not continuous. You should be able to find the proof in any decent (sufficiently sophisticated) textbook on Fourier analysis.